# java : dynamic code creation from database content using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to replace static code in my application using reflection.  I need to use reflection to instantiate objects based on the data from databases  without knowing in advance what objects I am going to use.

Can I find some examples and information regarding this as I am naive(not worked before) about using reflection. Any help is appreciated.

I don't have working knowledge of reflection concepts, went through some documentations.

Comment: You might just want to use [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)? You can specify the definition of the type of class used to serialize the object when deserializing...

Comment: I have edited it and the intent is to use reflection as there are other aspects which are not clear to me at this moment.

Comment: What makes this need reflection? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The need is be able to dynamically plug in classes based on the analysis from data in database. I agree it can be done in different ways but I need some pointers to implement it using reflection.